# How can I count how many of five properties in an object are non-null?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object test that is represented by this Typescript interface:

```
interface IWordForm {
    definition: string;
    sample1: string;
    sample2: string;
    sample3: string;
    sample4: string;
    sample5: string;
}
```

What I need is to create a function that will return a count based on how many of the sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4 and sample5 are defined not null;

I think I could do this using a series of if statements but is there a clean way that I could do using a modern browser function?

Comment: Loop over the keys and check

Comment: When you have a bunch of properties which have the same name except for a number … you should probably replace them with one property who's value is an array.

Comment: `Object.keys(word).filter(key => /^sample/.test(key) && word[key] != null).length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces ain't there at runtime, you cannot use Object.keys(). Use an explicit list of keys you want to check.

```
var count = ["definition", "sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5"].filter(k => k in obj && obj[k] != null).length;
```

or like this:

```
var iWordFormNonNullKeys = Array.prototype.filter.bind(
    ["definition", "sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5"],
    function(k){ return k in this && this[k] != null } //here you can't use a lambda-expression
);

var count = iWordFormNonNullKeys(someObj).length
```

> Why exactly can't he use Object.keys()

because there is no such thing as an Interface at runtime.

```
var obj = {
    //interface part
    definition: null,
    sample1: null,
    sample2: null,
    sample3: null,
    sample4: null,
    sample5: null,

    //non-interface-properties
    lorem: 13,
    ipsum: 14,
    dolor: 15,
    sit: 16,
}
```

obj matches the interface, wherever you pass it. 
But Object.keys() will also test the non-interface-properties and count 4 in this case. Although non of the interface-properties has a non-null value.

**Edit:** I was wrong.
You can use Object.keys(), if you have a good filter, that matches only the keys of your Interface.

```
var isValidKey = /^(?:sample[1-5]|definition)$/;
var count = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => isValidKey.test(k) && obj[k] != null).length
```

Comment: Why exactly can't he use `Object.keys()`?

Comment: Your example doesn't work anyhow, the ts compiler will complain that you have keys that are not defined in the interface. [Check this for example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Point%20%7B%0A%09x%3A%20number%3B%0A%09y%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20p%3A%20Point%20%3D%20%7B%20x%3A%204%2C%20y%3A%204%2C%20z%3A%205%7D)

Comment: that's not entirely true: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Point%20{%0A%09x%3A%20number%3B%0A%09y%3A%20number%3B%0A}%0A%2F%2Fcreating%0Avar%20p3d%20%3D%20{%20x%3A%204%2C%20y%3A%204%2C%20z%3A%205}%3B%0A%2F%2Fand%20then%20passing%20it%0Avar%20p%3APoint%20%3D%20p3d%3B%0A). I'm not sure, why it doesn't compile if you assign it directly.

Comment: Of course, because your `p3d` is of type `{ x: number, y: number, x: number}` (if you do `var p3d: Point = ...` then you get an error). Then you basically tell the compiler "the new variable `p` is going to be just the `Point` part of this new type". But if you're doing this, then you're missing the whole point of interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Lets Say your Object is

```
var datContract = {
      prop1: string,
      prop2: string,
      prop3: number,
      prop4: number,
      prop5: string,
  }
```

Then the Keys with not null values would be

```
 Object.keys(this.datContract).filter(x => this.datContract[x]!= undefined);
```

and the count would be

```
 Object.keys(this.datContract).filter(x => this.datContract[x]!= undefined).length;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could loop over the properties (keys) of the object using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and find only the ones that look like "sample*".

```
var count = 0;
Object.keys(x).forEach((key) => {
  if(key.indexOf('sample') === 0 && x[key] !== null) {
    count++;
  }
});
```

---

*Edit in reply to comment about properties on the interface*

In typescript, interfaces are purely a compile-time construct. At runtime, you can't determine what properties are from the object and what are from the interface.

For example, the Typescript:

```
interface IWordForm {
    definition: string;
    sample1: string;
    sample2: string;
    sample3: string;
    sample4: string;
    sample5: string;
}

class WordForm implements IWordForm {
    definition: string;
    sample1: string;
    sample2: string;
    sample3: string;
    sample4: string;
    sample5: string;
    sample6: string;
}
```

compiles to:

```
var WordForm = (function () {
    function WordForm() {
    }
    return WordForm;
}());
```

There is no actual JS that defines the interface.

Comment: you cannot use Object.keys(). It will process and count all keys on the object, not only the ones of the Interface!

Comment: that's exactly my point. You have to explicitely define the keys you want to test. And your test will also match "sample6" wich is not part of the interface

Comment: @CodingWithSpike This answer counts `null` values, which the OP didn't want.

Comment: Well, now it doesn't catch `undefined`. :-) If you use non strict equality (`!=`) it will catch both.

Comment: @Aaron but then it would also include `0` and empty string `''` ;)

Comment: @CodingWithSpike Nah that would be true for a falsy check, but `x != null` is *only* true for `null` and `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
let prefix = "sample",
    count = 0;

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (key.substring(0, prefix.length) === prefix) {
        count++;
    }
})
```

The [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) only returns the keys that are on the object, and not the attributes it inherits from the prototype, so it's safe to use.

---

### Edit

As @CodingWithSpike mentioned in the comments, regex might be a better solution:

```
let prefix = "sample",
    regex = new RexExp("^" + prefix),
    count = 0;

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (regex.test(key)) {
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: @CodingWithSpike that makes two of us

Comment: Your answer makes me wonder if `substring` `indexOf` or a regex would be most efficient...

Comment: @CodingWithSpike actually, I tend towards `regex`, but thought about it later..  It's how I do things in my code base, because you have the regex which is "compiled" once and then you just reuse it for each `test` call. But I haven't checked the benchmarks.

Comment: you cannot use Object.keys(). It will process and count all keys on the object, not only the ones of the Interface!

Comment: @Thomas True, that's why there's a check of each key in each iteration. You took his example way to specificaly. What happens if there are `sampleN` where `N` is 100? What happens if the data is coming from a server and he can't know how many of those exist?

Comment: The interface-definition in Typescript won't actually ever come from a server, because this whole thing has to be compiled and baked into your JS-fiile. if there are 100, or more keys like that: a) enunmerated keys are never a good sign, and b) you can write an oneliner tu build the Array of enumerated keys. explicitely matching the Interface.

Comment: @Thomas You need to differntiate between `typescript` and `javascript`. Some things make sense in one but not the other.  For example, your solution doesn't make much sense in javascript in opposed to the more generic solution I presented.  The typesrcipt interfaces are awesome for dev time, but once you make changes to your js code so that it will look nice with typescript then you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "cleanest" solution I can think of:

```
Object.keys(word).filter(key => /^sample/.test(key) && word[key] != null).length
```

Example:

```
function count(word:IWordForm):number {
    return Object.keys(word).filter(key => /^sample/.test(key) && word[key] != null).length;
}

count({definition: "123", sample1: "a"}); // 1
count({definition: "123", sample1: "a", sample2: "b"}); // 2
count({definition: "123", sample1: "a", sample2: null, sample3: undefined}); // 1
```

[Example in the playground here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IWordForm%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20definition%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20sample1%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20sample2%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20sample3%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20sample4%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20sample5%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20countSamples(word%3AIWordForm)%3Anumber%20%7B%0A%09return%20Object.keys(word).filter(key%20%3D%3E%20%2F%5Esample%2F.test(key)%20%26%26%20word%5Bkey%5D%20!%3D%20null).length%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20test(word%3AIWordForm%2C%20expected%3Anumber)%3Avoid%20%7B%0A%09let%20result%20%3D%20countSamples(word)%3B%0A%09let%20passed%20%3D%20result%20%3D%3D%3D%20expected%3B%0A%09console%5Bpassed%20%3F%20%22log%22%20%3A%20%22error%22%5D(passed%20%3F%20%22%5BPASS%5D%22%20%3A%20%22%5BFAIL%5D%22%2C%20word%2C%20%22returned%22%2C%20result%2C%20%22expected%22%2C%20expected)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atest(%7Bsample1%3A%20%22a%22%7D%2C%201)%3B%0Atest(%7Bsample1%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20sample2%3A%20%22b%22%7D%2C%202)%3B%0Atest(%7Bsample1%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20sample2%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20sample3%3A%20%22c%22%2C%20sample4%3A%20%22d%22%2C%20sample5%3A%20%22e%22%7D%2C%205)%3B%0Atest(%7Bdefinition%3A%20%22123%22%2C%20sample1%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20sample2%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20sample3%3A%20%22c%22%2C%20sample4%3A%20%22d%22%2C%20sample5%3A%20%22e%22%7D%2C%205)%3B%0Atest(%7Bdefinition%3A%20%22123%22%2C%20sample3%3A%20%22c%22%2C%20sample5%3A%20%22e%22%7D%2C%202)%3B%0Atest(%7Bdefinition%3A%20%22123%22%2C%20sample1%3A%20null%2C%20sample2%3A%20undefined%2C%20sample3%3A%20%22c%22%2C%20sample5%3A%20%22e%22%7D%2C%202)%3B).